# Getting the submittedValue from a xe:navigator item

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Why does this simple navigator code not add anything to the sessionScope var in the onItemClick event?

```
<xe:navigator id="navigator1">         
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xe:dominoViewListTreeNode filter="All.*" submitValue="#{javascript:return viewEntry.getName()}" var="viewEntry" href="page.xsp">
            <xe:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:database.getServer() + "!!" + "path//db.nsf"}]]></xe:this.databaseName>
        </xe:dominoViewListTreeNode>
    </xe:this.treeNodes>
                   
    <xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.clickedView = context.getSubmittedValue()}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:navigator>
```

The code is heavily inspired by XPages101 lesson 71: http://xpages101.net/xpages101/XPages101.nsf/0/4DB7580AC6931682802579A7004E74E7

As a workaround I am transferring the viewEntry.getName() as a parameter instead by using the following href:

```
<xe:this.href><![CDATA[#{javascript:"page.xsp?view="+viewEntry.getName();}]]></xe:this.href>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per,

The **href** attribute in the **xe:dominoViewListTreeNode** causes the server side event not to be executed at all. When clicking a node it just performs a HTTP GET to the selected page (page.xsp). If you remove it and redirect the user in the serverside code your sample should work:

```
<xe:navigator id="navigator1">         
  <xe:this.treeNodes>
     <xe:dominoViewListTreeNode filter="All.*" submitValue="#{javascript:return viewEntry.getName()}" var="viewEntry">
        <xe:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:database.getServer() + "!!" + "path//db.nsf"}]]></xe:this.databaseName>
    </xe:dominoViewListTreeNode>
  </xe:this.treeNodes>

  <xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
     <xp:this.action>
       <![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.clickedView = context.getSubmittedValue();
     context.redirectToPage("page");}]]>
     </xp:this.action>
  </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:navigator>
```

Another tip: using Expression Language you could shorten the formula for the submitValue attribute to:

```
submitValue="#{viewEntry.name}"
```

Comment: Ah, of course! Client-side always takes precedence over server-side. Thanks, Mark. I will test and accept later